# Rails rspec выводит слишком много

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, юнит-тесты, rspec

Использую rails 4.2.4 и rspec-rails 3.3.3

В файле `.rspec` только `--color`.

При запуске теста (rspec или rake) после стандартной ошибки идут очень много таких строк:

```
# /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
# /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:729:in `generate'
# /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:760:in `generate'
# /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:755:in `generate_extras'
# /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:750:in `extra_keys'
# /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:208:in `assign_parameters'
# /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controlle...
```

Как избавится от таких (`.../.rvm/gems/...`) строк?

Comment: Это норма. 
Это стек вызова метода, в котором произошла ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

### Эти строки вам нужны. От них лучше не избавляться.

Это ["stack trace"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace), называемый в народе "стектрейс".

Каждая последующая строчка в этом выводе показывает, откуда была вызвана предыдущая. Поломав это, вы скорее запутаетесь сами или запутаете ещё кого-нибудь, если столкнётесь со сколько-нибудь содержательными ошибками.

Потому что далеко не всегда реальная ошибка находится на поверхности стектрейса. Структурировать код так, чтобы они были на поверхности всегда, цель благородная. Но суровая реальность такова, что вам придётся погружаться глубже.

- Поскольку в Ruby передача в библиотеки собственного исполняемого кода обычное дело, у вас могут быть ситуации, когда "взрыв" произошёл (по строкам трейса, 1) у вас в коде, (2) вызванном внутри гема, (3) который был в свою очередь вызван в вашем коде. Если убрать строки гемов в стектрейсе, стектрейс будет содержать логическую дыру. Если не вспомнить о том, что строки гемов заглушены, то можно потратить много времени, ища вызов, которого нет.
- Ошибка запросто может быть и в геме. Почему бы и нет? Слепо доверять сторонним библиотекам не стоит: их тесты (если они есть) могут быть неполными.